# ORACLE: multiple column subqueries

Tags: oracle, select, subquery

This is from Oracle Database 10g: SQL Fundamentals.
Original Oracle textbook.
Francly speaking, this all is actual so far.

There is a task which troubles me:

**Display the last name, department name, and salary of any employee whose salary and commission match the salary and commission of many employee located in location ID 1700.**

The topic to be learned is multiple column subqueries. This mean that we can't deviate from the offered model which is:

```
SELECT column, column, ...
FROM table
WHERE (column, column, ...) IN
(SELECT column, column, ...
FROM table
WHERE condition);
```

Well, my database:

```
describe employees
Name           Null     Type         
-------------- -------- ------------ 
EMPLOYEE_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
FIRST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
EMAIL          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25) 
PHONE_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20) 
HIRE_DATE      NOT NULL DATE         
JOB_ID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) 
SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2)  
COMMISSION_PCT          NUMBER(2,2)  
MANAGER_ID              NUMBER(6)    
DEPARTMENT_ID           NUMBER(4)    

describe departments
Name            Null     Type         
--------------- -------- ------------ 
DEPARTMENT_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
DEPARTMENT_NAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) 
MANAGER_ID               NUMBER(6)    
LOCATION_ID              NUMBER(4)
```

There is a solution:

```
select
  e.last_name,
  d.department_name, 
  e.salary
from employees e, departments d
where e.department_id = d.department_id
and (salary, nvl(commission_pct, 0)) in
  (select salary, nvl(commission_pct, 0)
   from employees e, departments d
   where e.department_id = d.department_id
   and d.location_id = 1700);
```

SELECTED 36 ROWS.

Well, I started checking. It seems that employees from location 1700 duplicated against themselves.
Look: we take the whole list of employees and then juxtapose it with employees from location 1700. Of course, there will be duplicates.

I have prepared an excel file with some data (all employees, employees from location 1700, the result of my own desired result etc.). In the file it is more picturesque, with examples and so on. Please, have a look.

This is the file: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!150&authkey=!ADMRAE466BIunQM

Well, what I would like to do is to control that no employee is compared with themselves.
This was my variant bevore I checked the solution.

```
select lnme, dpt, slry 
from
(
  select       
      employee_id eid,
      last_name lnme, 
      salary slry, 
      nvl(commission_pct,0) cpct,
      d.department_name dpt,
      location_id
  from employees e
  left join departments d
  on e.department_id = d.department_id
)
where (slry, cpct) in
(select 
    employee_id ide,
    salary slry, 
    nvl(commission_pct,0) cpct    
from employees e
join departments d
on e.department_id = d.department_id and location_id = 1700)
and ide <> eid
```

I wanted to make sure that no employee is compared with the same employee. But I failed.

Could you comment on all this situation:
1. Whether I'm completely wrong and the solution of Oracle is perfect.
2. If Oracle is wrong, could you help me with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks you to identify *any employee* whose salary and commission matches any combination of salary and salary of employees in Department 1700.  The question doesn't say to exclude employees from that department.  So it is quite correct for them to appear in the result set.

> "One employee can't match themselves."

You're not matching employees, you're matching *salaries* .  It just so happens that the list of target salaries is generated from a sub-query on department 1700: it could just as easily be a list of numbers from a CSV file.

---

Let's have a thought experiment.  There are three employees in department 1700:

```
name       | salary  | comm
-----------+---------+-----
CHIP       |  10,100 |    0  
RUNCITER   |  12,200 |    0  
CONLEY     |  10,500 |    0
```

Nobody else in the company earns above 10K.

So what is the answer to the question: how many employee have a salary and commission which match the salary and commission of any employee located in department 1700?

1. Three
2. Zero

Then Joe gets a modest raise and the salaries look like this:

```
name       | salary  | comm
-----------+---------+-----
CHIP       |  10,500 |    0  
RUNCITER   |  12,200 |    0  
CONLEY     |  10,500 |    0
```

So what is the answer to the same question now?

1. Still three
2. Two

The answer is 'three' in both cases.

Why?

Because SQL is a set-based programming language, and the set of all employees who earn the exact salary and commission as employees in department 1700 must include all employees who work in department 1700.

There is a different set, which is the set of all employees who earn the exact salary and commission as employees in department 1700 who don't themselves work in department 1700.  But that is not the set the SQL Fundamentals quiz is looking for.

Comment: English is not my native language. But! I consulted an Oxford dictionary. http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/match_2 "if two things match or if one thing matches another, they are the same or very similar". One employee can't match themselves. And logically it wold be clumsy even without Oxford. No, that is not the case.

Comment: @Pepperwork: If you don't want to list the employees from Dept 1700, then simply say so in your outermost query: `... AND e.department_id != 1700`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I want some of them to be present. If an employee from 1700 has another coleague in the same location with appropriate remuniration, they must all be in the selection. But not one employee without any match.

Comment: @Pepperwork - that is a different question.  It might be a legitimate programming problem but it is *not* the question you posted.

Comment: @Pepperwork: then your condition must be that the matching employee in 1700 is not the current employee; the two employee numbers must be different.

Comment: @APC, my initial post was edited by somebody. And I can't get my original text back. This is my carma. I still believe that I understand the task correctly. We should take each employee outside and inside the location 1700 (full list), then compare them with emploiees within that location, but if not with themselves.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, well, yes. That is the idea. Look at the last line of the code. I tried to do that but failed.

Comment: @Pepperwork - the text of the question as you posted matches the original text in the SQL Fundamentals quiz.  So that makes them the same thing :)  There is no mention of excluding employees from department 1700.  So please accept that this is an elaboration you have invented.  If you really want an answer to this variant please edit your question to reflect the change.

Comment: Well, I can't believe oneself can match himself.

Comment: @Pepperwork - although I think your variation is a twisted logic.  It makes even less sense to exclude *some* employees from Department 1700 than to exclude all of them.

Comment: @APC, have you had a look at my excel file? Could you recommend me how to achieve the result from the self_check sheet?

Comment: @Pepperwork - normally with this many comments I would suggest moving to chat but I can't see the point.  If you don't understand by now that the question is asking you to match salaries not employees I can't imagine what else we can say to convince you.

Comment: of course, not employees but salary and the commission. but the revenue of employees. and one employee can't match himself or herself. as well as one salary cant match itself.

Comment: In the Real World, if you had a requirement that you found was not precise then you can ask for more clear instructions. But this is an exercise from a book, so while it's good that you identified a possible lack of precision you cannot ask the author. Since you believe that there are two ways of understanding the question, implement answers to both of them and be happy that you have learned.